# Pre-built developer ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm searching for a Ubuntu (or other Linux distribution) VM with pre-installed Maven, JDK, Code-Editor, etc. It's pretty annoying to install all these tools every time you set up a new development environment so I was wondering if there are pre-built VM images for VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3):

You can use vagrant boxes for that.

A public catalog of boxes is available at:
https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search

An example of what you are looking for could be:
https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64